# Code is not recognizing the name view in xaml (Xamarin Forms Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PermeabilidadeSolo.Pages.TipoSoloPage"
             Title="Tipo de Solo">
  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="lvTipoSolo" ItemSelected="TipoSoloSelected" />
  </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage>
```

When I try to use the listview in my file.cs it doesnt work, the file.cs doesnt recognize lvTipoSolo

Comment: Show us the code where you want to access the name.

Comment: `namespace PermeabilidadeSolo.Pages
{
    public partial class TipoSoloPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TipoSoloPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> TipoSolo = new List<string>()
            {
                "Tipo 1",
                "Tipo 2",
                "Tipo 3",
                "Tipo 4"
            };

            lvTipoSolo.ItemsSource = TipoSolo;
        }
        
        public async void TipoSoloSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabelaPage());
        }
    }
}`

Comment: what kinda error show's ? The name `lvTipoSolo` cannot be accessed? Try to clean the both project's, Portable and Target,if doesn't work, go to your root project folder, and erase obj and bin folders,and rebuild again!

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the solution... I just gave up working with Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case Visual Studio 2017 created the XAML file with the *Custom Tool* property set to `MSBuild:Compile`. After changing it to `MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml` it generated the private fields corresponding to the `x:Name` attributes.